# ASP.NET MVC ModelState isn't valid despite validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a poll site. I'm passing a `PollVM` to my `View`, which includes `PollModel` and `VotesModel` in it.

`PollVM.cs`

```cs
public class PollVM
{
    public PollModel Poll { get; set; }
    public VotesModel Votes { get; set; }
}
```

`PollModel.cs`

```cs
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public int PollId { get; set; }
public string? PollTitle { get; set; }
public List<PollOptionModel>? PollOptions { get; set; }
public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

`VotesModel.cs`

```cs
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public int PollId { get; set; }
public int OptionId { get; set; }
public string? VoterIP { get; set; }
```

`index.cshtml`

```cs
@model AoTWiki.Models.PollVM
<form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Poll" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Poll.PollOptions" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Votes" />

            <div class="card mb-3 text-center bg-dark" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
                <div class="card-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                    <h2 class="card-title text-light">@Model.Poll.PollTitle</h2>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Votes.PollId" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-check m-4 align-content-start align-items-start">
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Poll.PollOptions.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            <li class="list-inline-item text-light">
                                <input asp-for="Votes.OptionId" value="@Model.Poll.PollOptions[i].OptionId" name="Votes.OptionId" id="VoteOption_@Model.Poll.PollOptions[i]" type="radio" class="form-check-input" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Votes.OptionId"></span>
                                <label class="form-check-label text-light" style="font-size: 25px;">@Model.Poll.PollOptions[i].Option</label>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    @{
                        if (Model.Votes.OptionId == 0)
                        {
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">VOTE</button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <i class="text-warning">You have already voted</i>

                            <br />
                        }
                    }
                    Created At @Model.Poll.CreatedAt
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

`PollController.cs`

```cs
public IActionResult index()
{
    var ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
    var votesDb = (_mongo.ConnectToMongo<VotesModel>("votes")).Find(x => x.VoterIP == ip).FirstOrDefault();
    if (votesDb == null)
        (_mongo.ConnectToMongo<VotesModel>("votes")).InsertOne(new VotesModel { VoterIP = ip });
    PollVM newPoll = new PollVM()
    {
        Poll = (_mongo.ConnectToMongo<PollModel>("polls")).Find(x => x.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault(),
        Votes = (_mongo.ConnectToMongo<VotesModel>("votes")).Find(x => x.VoterIP == ip).FirstOrDefault()
    };

    return View(newPoll);
}

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult index(PollVM poll)
 {
     var ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var votesGetVoter = Builders<VotesModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.VoterIP, ip);

         var votesUpdatePoll = Builders<VotesModel>.Update.Set(x => x.PollId, poll.Votes.PollId).Set(x => x.OptionId, poll.Votes.OptionId);
                var updatePollId = _mongo.ConnectToMongo<VotesModel>("votes").UpdateOne(votesGetVoter, votesUpdatePoll, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

         return RedirectToAction(nameof(index), "home");
     }

     return View(poll);
}
```

When I put a breakpoint at `return View(poll);`, I keep getting this error:
[image: modelstate]

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

`Values` from `ModelState`
[image: values]

**EDIT 2:**
Expanded `Errors Count = 1`
[image: errors]

Comment: When inside the breakpoint, will you hover over ModelState object and check the property `Values`? Include a screenshot if possible.

Comment: this is what i got.

Comment: Can you please expand the `Errors Count = 1`

Comment: this is the output

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult index(PollVM poll)
 {
     var ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         var votesGetVoter = Builders<VotesModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.VoterIP, ip);

         var votesUpdatePoll = Builders<VotesModel>.Update.Set(x => x.PollId, poll.Votes.PollId).Set(x => x.OptionId, poll.Votes.OptionId);
                var updatePollId = _mongo.ConnectToMongo<VotesModel>("votes").UpdateOne(votesGetVoter, votesUpdatePoll, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

         return RedirectToAction(nameof(index), "home");
     }
     else
     {
       IList<string> IList = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(v => v.ErrorMessage + " " + v.Exception).ToList();
       string ErrorMsg = ""; 
       foreach (var item in IList)
        {
        if (ErrorMsg == "")
            ErrorMsg = item;
        else
            ErrorMsg += "," + item;
        }
     }

     return View(poll);
}
```

Comment: It'd be nice to take a little troubleshooting piece like this and make it an Attribute. [PrintOutModelStateErrors] I'm surprised its not in the ObjectBrowser? Arhh it is, OP just showed

Comment: what output do i get from this?

Comment: You will get  model state error in ErrorMsg field.

Comment: the errors i got are `The Votes field is required.` and `The Poll field is required.` like the screenshot from EDIT 2 in my original post